# Can I reduce these sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

1. **The boy who lives in Kolkata is my brother.**

Can I reduce it to

- The boy living in Kolkata is my brother.

2. **Ram, who works in your company, is a good boy.**

Can I reduce it to

- Ram, working in your company, is a good boy.

3.**John, who has just slapped you, is her brother.**

Can I reduce it to

- John, having just slapped you ,is her brother.

Please let me know if these reductions are correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

There must be many boys living in Kolkata, but you can use either form of sentence (1) to distinguish your brother from among a group of boys who come from different places.

The other two sentences, where the *who* clause provides additional information about a named person, can't be changed in that way.

Answer (score -3):

You could do these reductions like this, yes.  They all make sense.

```
The boy who lives in Kolkata is my brother.
```

Can be reduced to

```
The boy living in Kolkata is my brother.
```

This is very passive. One could also say

```
My young brother lives in Kolkata.
```

Depending on how young he is. If he is a teenager or an adult, it would be insulting to call them a "boy".

Your next set of simplifications

```
Ram, who works in your company, is a good boy.
Ram, working in your company, is a good boy.
```

Is also fine, but I would consider choosing a word that gives the sense of "working in your company".

```
Your employee, Ram, is a good boy.
```

Again, "boy" seems to imply a child.

Next is

```
John who has just slapped you is her brother.
John having just slapped you is her brother.
```

You need commas:

```
John, who has just slapped you, is her brother.
John, having just slapped you, is her brother.
```

These are passive sentences and so you could make them more active by saying:

```
Her brother, John, just slapped you!
```

Comment: **John, having just slapped you, is her brother** signifies that John would not be her brother if he had not just slapped you. Compare:: **John, having drunk several beers, staggered around the dance floor.**

Comment: I strongly disagree that "John, having just slapped you, is her brother" is fluent or correct.  And there is nothing passive about those sentences.

Comment: @RonaldSole I was also thinking of that. What if we don't use the commas? Is it correct to say " The boy having gone to your house is my student" ? If it's correct, is it the reduced form of " The boy who has gone to your house is my student".

Comment: @SahilLaskar No, it doesn't work. The phrase **having done x** is used to imply a consequence in what follows. And the boy is not your student as a consequence of visiting someone's house.. But the reduced form is fine. **who has gone to your house** serves to identify the boy., With commas around **who has gone to your house** would also work, but as a non-restrictive or non defining clause. It simply adds information.