# I'm not as you think or I'm not as think I'm

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, clauses, redundancy

Let's look at these sentences.

> - **I'm not as you think I am.**
> - **You're more beautiful than you think you are.**

Can I rewrite these sentences as:

- *I'm not as you think.*
- *You're more beautiful than you think.*

Which ones are more recommended? Are these structures grammatical?

Comment: Asking if something is correct is considered proofreading and off-topic here. Your question may be voted to be closed unless you can update it. Did you do some research? Can you include that research in your question? Is there a reason why you think what you've written might be wrong?

Comment: @Astralbee This appears to be a question about how to correctly reduce sentences with "think", which is a specific aspect of English, not proofreading. Before leaving these comments on questions that happen to ask if a particular sentence is correct, please ask yourself if the intent is to get some writing proofread (off topic), or to check understanding of a specific aspect of English (on topic).

Comment: @gotube whatever the intent, there's still no research, and that puts it off-topic, too. Also, asking what is "recommended" is opinion-based, and off-topic. Before answering poor-quality questions, please ask yourself if you're actually benefitting the site and future ELLs searching.

Comment: @Astralbee I just wanted to know if those sentences could be reduced or not.

Comment: @SahilLaskar Yes, and a number of your previous questions are just a list of sentences asking if they can be reduced, so it seems that you are not learning a point of English on if and how sentences can be reduced, you are just getting people to check them for you to see if they have been reduced correctly, and that sort of question is off-topic here. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/321008/can-i-reduce-these-sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your rewritten versions are correct and natural.

Reducing sentences with "think" that way sounds more formal or academic.